# Install meteor application on Windows server

Tags: windows, meteor, installation, windows-installer

I am unable to preform correct search on this topic, due to the confusion on meteor platform installation on Windows. That is why have to ask like this, although this is probably somewhere explained on the Internet.

I am looking for way to make Windows wizard installation of the meteor web application. Ideally, web application should be packaged to installation file and available to install on Windows server. After installation, the server will host regular meteor web application.

This is like a deployment via manual installation.

Any resources are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use https://github.com/onmodulus/demeteorizer  and deploy NodeJs